# WordPress Theme Displaying Incorrectly In Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having a problem with http://taxlienagents.com/ and how it is displaying in Google Chrome. When I open the site in Google Chrome, the center Tab Area seems to cover the main text above it. If you take a look at [this link](http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/8869/taxliensite.jpg), you should be able to see what I am talking about versus when opening the site in FireFox. I tried playing around with the Z-Index, but that didn't seem to fix it. The other issue that I seem to be having is with rolling over the buttons ("How to," "Coaching," and "Done for You") the highlight only covers about 2/3 of the button, I think this is an issue with FancyBox.

If anyone could give me any advice on how to fix this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Whenever you have a problem like this, one of the best things to do is validate your code - I'm giving you the link here: [W3C validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftaxlienagents.com%2F).  Note that you have 52 errors.  AFTER you've cleaned all those up, you are likely to be a lot closer to being able to figure out why it differs between FF and Chrome.

Comment: All of the Validation issues are attribute related and don't seem to be releated to the Tab area.

Comment: That may be, but you'll be surprised at how much simpler it is to troubleshoot this if you DO get those cleaned up.

Comment: I've gotten it down to 10 errors which I am not sure what to do about all of which are "is not a member of a group specified for any attribute". I am still having problems and I am not sure what to do with those since I wasn't the original developer for this theme

Answer (score 1):

you have several JS related errors :

- 1 You load jQuery 2 times, in 2 different versions (one on-site, one from google)

*--> remove one of them*

- 2 you have an error in adia-paper.js that keeps Fancybox from triggering right - and it blocks the JS execution.

*--> try to change*

$(document).ready(function() {

```
   $("#form-trigger").fancybox({
    'width'             : 600,
    'height'            : 526,
.....
```

to

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
    //contact form modal window
   jQuery("#form-trigger").fancybox({
    'width'             : 600,
    'height'            : 526,
    'autoScale'         : true,
    'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
    'transitionOut'     : 'fade'
```

- 3 you trigger fancybox on a non-existing DIV (#form-trigger)

  --> although it is not the major cause for your problem , it is better to trigger JS only when needed...

Jquery - when encountring a big issue, blocks and stops from executing any functions further down the line, and your "slideshow" is also JS driven .
Different browsers treat those errors differently - and it is also depending on your own browser settings.

FF - Firebug Chrome and Opera all give the same consul errors.

If you fix all those problems and the problem persist - we can keep on de-bugging - but I am pretty sure that one of those, or all together are the culprit..

**EDIT I** you still have other errors - but I do not think they are the problem. I do believe however that it can be because you edited the letabs JS and added some expression regarding height. strangely chrome sets the div height `le-tabs_content_container` to 58 px .. i believe it comes from the script . try to set the heights for all the parent / children divs (and remove that script) - It worked for me instantly on the debugger..

Comment: I've fixed all those errors and I still seem to be having problems

Comment: I see that with the Chrome Debugger. I just removed the script I added and tried setting the DIV height to 370px, but it still seems to automatically be setting it to 58px

Comment: On my debugger when I set a height it works - you can try setting it also on the container div, and try also adding BLOCK..

Comment: I was able to use !important to set the height for the initial tab and it seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

Here are your issues of tabs [http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftaxlienagents.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://taxlienagents.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Before asking for help, help yourself by validating your code @ validator.w3.org

Comment: I've gotten it down to 10 errors which I am not sure what to do about all of which are "is not a member of a group specified for any attribute". I am still having problems and I am not sure what to do with those since I wasn't the original developer for this theme